# How To Calculate Daily Volatility?

Tags: financial-literacy, calculation

I'm working in SQL Server and I'm trying to find the daily volatility of a stock's price.  Is it simply day2price/day2price-1?  Is that considered daily volatility?  Or, is there something else to it?  Thanks?

Comment: You'll need to clarify what you mean by "daily volatility". Volatility is the standard deviation of periodic logarithmic returns (your formula would calculate a single daily absolute return), so if you're looking at daily returns, you can't calculate volatility since there's just one data point. So you either need to look at many daily returns or many intra-day returns. Or do you mean _implied_ volatility (meaning implied from option prices)?

Comment: I would look at something like the day's range divided by the previous day's close.  I seem to recall reading something that suggested (H-L)/(H+L).  I doubt that it matters which way you do it as long as it's done the same way consistently.  Either way, you'll get a representation of the size of today's move (volatility) compared to earlier  days and you'll be able to see if there's  a trending increase or decrease in this number.  This calculation is different from looking at a longer period of data and determining the average daily volatility.

Comment: Thanks, both.  I think I need to pick a duration of time, like 30 days, or whatever, and take the standard deviation of that.  Is that correct?

Comment: That's one way - the time period is fairly arbitrary, you just need to identify what the time period is when you present it (e.g. call is "30D historical volatility")

Comment: Formula here: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/86858/11768

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like a standard deviation formula.

SQL server has STDEV.(But you should use something like Python, R, C++ or Google Sheets)

So if the average stock price is $100 with a STDEV of $10 over the last 6 months.

With 1 standard deviation, its 68% likely the price should fall between $110 and $90 tomorrow. if the empirical rule is correct.

If you want I can make a google sheet and link it as an example if you would like?