# General formula to understand standard deviation of a stock price over a time horizon?

Tags: stocks, volatility

A book that I'm reading (Paul Wilmott, Derivatives) states the following:

The standard deviation of the stock price over this time horizon is
$$ \sigma S = \sqrt(1/52) $$

where, the time horizon is one week.

Why is this the std. dev? Does this mean that the general formula for the standard deviation of a stock price over time horizon $t$ is :
$$ \sigma S \sqrt(t)$$

I'm assuming that the $\sqrt(t)$ is for converting annual returns to weekly returns?

Comment: You probably want [quant.se]. not least because that site allows mathjax and this one doesn't. Flag a moderator for migration.

Comment: @AakashM alright, i'll do that, thanks.

Comment: fyi [How can I calculate the volatility(standard deviation) of a stock price?](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/86858/11768)